# Executing *.reg File

Tags: c#, file, regedit

I have a problem. I execute the code like below. after that I looked at the regedit file, the "test.reg" file didnt add. what do you think about the problem

content of the regedit file is :

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\efe]

"key1"="value"
"key2"="value2"
```

the code is :

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s " + @"D:\Projects\efe\efe\bin\Debug\test.reg");
        regeditProcess.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

thanks for your advice...

Comment: Are you sure your application has administrative rights ? . If yes try to put reg file into root of your application and change D:\... to test.reg only .

Comment: You need to access the registry as administrator. Do you run VS as admin? Do you get any uncaught exceptions?

Comment: i didnt get any exception.and i am sure about administrative on regedit. i have it

Comment: Did you try executing the same thing with Command Prompt or transfering reg file into root of application and then start ? with only test.reg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have administrative rights this should work if not you could try to create registry keys from c# directly :

```
   Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\efe");
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\efe",true).SetValue("key1", "value", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);
```

I typed code from the head so maybe you would have to make some changes. And for this you need to have administrative rights on your application also.

Comment: i tried the your code but i get the exception. and the exception is : "The parameter is incorrect." on "Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\efe");"

Comment: another exception. the exception is : "Cannot write to the registry key." on this "Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node\efe").SetValue("key1", "value", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String);"

Comment: You don't have administrative privileges it is a Unauthorized exception .

Comment: I edited once again it was my error . I didn't put ,true on OpenSubKey. Try it now.

Comment: Not a problem :) . I'am glad i helped.